# Definition list vs. Unordered list with headings - which makes more semantic sense?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup

Let's say you had something like a TV show listing, where you had a show title, and a show description. You want the listing to be **accessible** for people with disabilities as well.

Would it make more sense to use a definition list:

```
<dl>
    <dt>...title...</dt><dd>...description...</dd>
    ...
</dl>
```

Or an unordered list with headings?

```
<ul>
    <li><h3>...title...</h3><p>...description...</p></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Which makes more semantic sense and will respond better to **screen readers**? (knowing that they can both be styled the same way)

Comment: You have completely ignored the second point: accessibility and screen readers.

Comment: the “second point” is not reflected in the heading at all, a separate issue, and very vague.

Comment: Screen readers usually have a special buffer for headings which allow the user to scan just the headings, not sure if they do for `dt`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using HTML 4.01, you shouldn't use [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) as it's defined as "*definition* list" (and your example does not consist of terms and their definitions). If you are using HTML5, the use of `dl` is fine, because the definition of [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) changed.

Using headings inside of `li` might be a bit problematic regarding the document outline. The scope of a heading would include the start of the next `li`: `<li><!--scope start--><h3>title</h3><p>description</p></li><li><!--scope end--><h3>…`. By using `section` (resp. `article`), this could be avoided.

So, for HTML5, I think the following ways are possible:

### `dl`

```
<dl>

  <dt>Title1</dt>
  <dd>Description1</dd>

  <dt>Title2</dt>
  <dd>Description2</dd>

</dl>
```

That would be my favorite, if you only want to provide title and description for each show (if not, see the last example).

### `ul` + `section`

```
<ul>

  <li>
    <section>
      <h1>Title1</h1>
      <p>Description1</p>
    </section>
  </li>

  <li>
    <section>
      <h1>Title2</h1>
      <p>Description2</p>
    </section>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I don't like that very much. The list isn't adding much here, so why not omit it? (see next example)

### headings only

```
<section>
  <h1>Title1</h1>
  <p>Description1</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Title2</h1>
  <p>Description2</p>
</section>
```

Instead of `section` the `article` element might be possible, too.

You could also omit `section` (or `article`) and use headings only (in the case of `section` it wouldn't change the meaning); in that case you'd need to apply the correct heading level.

### headings + `dl`

If you want to provide additional metadata (maybe in the future), I'd go with the following markup:

```
<section>
  <h1>Title1</h1>
  <dl>
    <dt>Description</dt>
    <dd>…</dd>
    <dt>Rating</dt>
    <dd>…</dd>
    <dt>Time</dt>
    <dd>…</dd>
    <dt>Length</dt>
    <dd>…</dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't recomend using `ul`+`h1` and so does the W3C: *Note: While it is conforming to include heading elements inside li elements, it likely does not convey the semantics that the author intended. A heading starts a new section, so a heading in a list implicitly splits the list into spanning multiple sections.*

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, that's what I thought. But if you explicitly use `section`, this should be no problem anymore, I guess.

Comment: From what I can tell, `section`s create their own world or bubble within a document. On the other hand `ul`/`ol` convey that *these guys (`li`) stick together*, so you have a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the former. First, it seems to make more sense to me just based on the *content*.

But that's me. I think the markup should reflect the document structure, and since (as you say) the CSS can style it either way, why not make the markup reflect the content? A list containing items that contain a header for a title, followed by a description seems a bit of overkill to me.

But, hey. You know what they say about opinions.

Answer (score 1):

In this case using a Definition list makes much more sense. Aside from this though, is it really necessary to use a list at all? It may make more sense just to use your Heading tags appropriately on the page wit a  tag (x= 2-6) and have everything apply under the header of that. TV Shows in specific it may not make sense to use a "List" to display them with definitions or anything else. Again, they can be styled however, so i'm only worried about sematics with this.

Hope this helps
Zach